# " Returned error: intrinsic gas too low" trying to deploy a contract on rinkeby

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, error, out-of-gas

I'm trying to deploy a contract on rinkeby testnet and I receive this error message:
"Returned error: intrinsic gas too low".

This is my code:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address1,(err,txCount)=> {
    let rawTx={
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('5','gwei')),
        from: address1,
        to: null,
        data: '0x' + bytecode
    }

    const tx = new Ethereumjs(rawTx, { chain: 'rinkeby' })
    tx.sign(address1Key);
    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
        .on('receipt', console.log);
})
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP :)

I tried changing gasLimit and gasPrice but always same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a complex transaction that makes the gas fee unpredictable. Please see:

[https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-resolving-metamask-error-codes/#:~:text=Also%2C%20there's%20a%20fairly%20common,less%20than%20what%20is%20required](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-resolving-metamask-error-codes/#:%7E:text=Also%2C%20there%27s%20a%20fairly%20common,less%20than%20what%20is%20required).